# How to run conditional scripts on Elastic Beanstalk according to environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, devops

I'll be running a Rails application on Elastic Beanstalk and I'll have both Web and Worker environments. The problem is that, since they both share the same code, I need to run some specific ebextensions on the worker environment (to initialize the worker process) and some specific scripts on the web (to initialize the app server). How can I separate the two scripts on different folders inside .ebextensions folder and tell Elastic Beanstalk to run then according to an environment variable?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach that is not ideal but that works. Always run the same steps in all environments. Write a shell script to encapsulate the commands you want to conditionally run. Have the shell script test for the existence of an environment variable and run the commands if that environment variable is set.
Here's an illustration on how to implement this:

### 1/ add a config file `.ebextensions/worker_job.config`

```
files:
  "/home/webapp/worker_job.sh" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: webapp
    group: webapp
    content: |
      #!/bin/sh
      if [ -z "$RUN_WORKER_JOB" ]; then
        echo 'RUN_WORKER_JOB is not set, skipping RUN_WORKER_JOB';
      else
        echo 'RUN_WORKER_JOB is set, running RUN_WORKER_JOB'
        # run useful worker commands
      fi

container_commands:
  00_worker_job:
    command: /home/webapp/worker_job.sh
```

### 2/ set the `RUN_WORKER_JOB` on selected environments

Using the AWS console, select the environment you want the commands to run in. Open the `Software Configuration` tool and set an environment variable called `RUN_WORKER_JOB`. Make sure that environment variable is not set in the environments you don't want your commands to run in.

### Note:

Set a convention and call the scripts, variables and files in a consistent way: `worker_job.sh`, `worker_job.config`, `RUN_WORKER_JOB`, etc...

Comment: Not ideal, as you say, but workable for some situations. This feels like a missing feature that AWS needs to address—something this type of workaround can't help with is environment-specific config *for Elastic Beanstalk* instead of instance-level scripts. E.g. I have staging and production environments for a single application, and I only want to [enable a bunch of custom CloudWatch metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/health-enhanced-cloudwatch.html#health-enhanced-cloudwatch-metrics) on production because they have a cost.

Comment: I have found this [aws topic](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=685803) and if found it very useful

Comment: As an alternative, you could just create the `worker_job.sh` file unconditionally, then use the `test` option in `container_commands` (see [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands)), e.g. add this line to `00_worker_job`: `test: test $RUN_WORKER_JOB == "something"` (depending on you actual value for `RUN_WORKER_JOB`, of course)

Comment: @djvg your suggestion seems to be more recent. Might end up repeating bulks of commands for each condition, but still works. Any other suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Altogether I think this is a missing feature that AWS ought to offer first-class support for in the future, or more obvious and coherent first-class support—[saved configurations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html) help for EB option settings and resources (extra custom infrastructure), but I don't believe they can include on-instance commands, and their distinction and precedence from `.ebextensions` is messy and confusing for a team to have to understand (you can define resources and settings in either `.ebextensions` files or saved configurations…). EB is clearly designed for one application to have multiple environments, so `.ebextensions` unawareness of that seems conspicuous.

Solutions like @yacc's are workable for situations that boil down to minor differences in scripts between environments, which might suffice for the OP's question. It gets messy though, and doesn't help at all *for EB configuration and custom resources* instead of on-instance commands, such as if I want to [enable a bunch of custom CloudWatch metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/health-enhanced-cloudwatch.html#health-enhanced-cloudwatch-metrics) or [a multi-instance ElastiCache cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-environment-resources-elasticache.html) only for production and/or worker environments, but not staging.

For that, saved configurations can help:

```
$ eb config save staging
$ cp .elasticbeanstalk/saved_configs/{staging,production}-sc.cfg.yml

# Add production-specific option settings, resources, etc.:
$ $EDITOR .elasticbeanstalk/saved_configs/production-sc.cfg.yml

# Save the config to S3:
$ eb config put production --cfg production-sc

# Apply the config to the environment:
$ eb config production --cfg production-sc
```

I remove any secrets from the saved configs like sensitive environment variable values and then check `.elasticbeanstalk/saved_configs` into source control for repeatable environment recreation in the future. ([This [useful] article](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx1YHAJ5EELY54J/Using-the-Elastic-Beanstalk-EB-CLI-to-create-manage-and-share-environment-config) suggests that moving the files into the root of `.elasticbeanstalk/` may be preferable for the CLI's `.gitignore` conventions). Of course you could do first-time production env setup in the web console and then save and modify that, instead of starting from a copy of staging.

It might also be possible to achieve some of this within `.ebextensions` files using [CloudFormation condition functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html) for resources—I haven't tried this yet but I'll update my answer if I have the chance to find what input parameters EB gives to CloudFormation ([it looks like](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-resources.html) `AWSEBEnvironmentName` will work).